# Winrt xaml page takes times to load, show I want to show Loader

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am working on a winrt xaml application. I have a page that contains too many controls on it. When I click on a tile of main page that loads this big page application gets hang and after some time its navigates to that page. I get feedback from MS to show some kind of loader so that user get feeling of something happening. I applied a loader but nothing happens.
Is there any way?

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    App.ViewModel.IsDataLoading = Visibility.Visible;//Binded with Loader visibility 
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ProjectListPage));
    break;
}
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

The techniques used in the extended splash screen are exactly what you are wanting here. A splash screen does not need to be limited to the first page of an app, by the way. If you have a legit slow-loading page, this is the way to do it.

Ref: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/05/walkthrough-windows-8-extended-splash.html

Best of luck!